# Strange pytz import issue -- pytz.UnknownTimeZoneError with valid timezone

Tags: python, import, pytz

I am having trouble importing a valid timezone on a pytz install.

When I run this:

```
python -c "import pytz; print pytz.timezone('America/New_York')"
```

In my home folder I have this output:

```
$ python -c "import pytz; print pytz.timezone('America/New_York')"
America/New_York
```

But if I cd into a different folder off of my home directory, I get this output:

```
$ cd webapp/
$ python -c "import pytz; print pytz.timezone('America/New_York')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pytz/__init__.py", line 173, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'America/New_York'
```

It seems to be loading pytz incorrectly..? Is there a way I can figure out why it's loading it differently, and how I can restore default behavior? Thanks!

Comment: misspell the timezone name on purpose and repeat the commands. Compare paths to `pytz/__init__.py`. Are they the same in both cases?

Comment: Do you have `pytz` directory in `webapp` directory?

Comment: "Do you have pytz directory in webapp directory?"

Ugh -- yes. That's the problem. I completely wasn't paying attention to that. Thank you!