# Unable to deploy to gae: "Unable to assign value 'America/Chicago' to attribute 'timezone'"

Tags: google-app-engine

I used to be able to deploy, but something in my local environment has changed. Other devs I work with can still deploy from the same repo, so I know it must be something on my mac, but I can't figure out what. The deploy actually works up until the point of updating the crons:

```
[localhost] local: appcfg.py --oauth2 --version=prod update_cron .
01:39 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Error parsing yaml file:
Unable to assign value 'America/Chicago' to attribute 'timezone':
timezone 'America/Chicago' is unknown
  in "./cron.yaml", line 5, column 13

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'appcfg.py --oauth2 --version=prod update_cron .'

Aborting.
```

cron.yaml:

```
cron:

- description: remove orphaned revisions

  url: /bible_importer/revisions/orphaned

  schedule: every day 04:00

  timezone: America/Chicago

  target: import

- description: remove orphaned fragment sets

  url: /bible_importer/fragments/orphaned

  schedule: every day 04:30

  timezone: America/Chicago

  target: import
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange it should work. For not check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoneinfo_time_zones you can use `US/Central` which is equivalent to try to see if the problem is there.

Comment: I tried US/Central and unfortunately I got the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you look into [GAE's SDK for crons](https://github.com/AppScale/gae_sdk/blob/master/google/appengine/api/croninfo.py), it's using pytz to do the timezone conversion, which seems to Raise the exception you are watching [even when it doesn't find the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028464/strange-pytz-import-issue-pytz-unknowntimezoneerror-with-valid-timezone) when calling timezone() for the first time.

It also seems that [pytz is not included directly in GAE's SDK] due to it's heavy weight.

So all points [to you having the need to install this lib independently](https://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/issues/detail?id=4).

Hope you get it fixed.